# Set returned Range object from the Copy() method in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-2003

I have used the Copy() method on a filtered List range in Excel 2003 using a macro and I want to grab the returned range and count the rows (so I can check I've copied more than one row. However I get an 'Object required' error.

I am told by VBA reference on Microsoft's website that the Copy() method returns a range object. However from the code this appears to not be the case. Please advise!

Thanks.

```
For J = 1 To .ListObjects.Count
    ' Filter
    .ListObjects(J).Range.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CritRange
    Set CopiedRange = .ListObjects(J).Range.Copy ' Object required error
    If CopiedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    {etc...}
```

Comment: If that is your accepted answer you should post it as an answer and mark it as a solved.  So that others like myself would know your question was solved.

Comment: I know, I couldn't because I was too new a member at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesn't return a range object on a Copy() operation. I tried testing the range for the row count before copying it but this didn't work without taking into account especially for visible rows only. Hence I needed to write a new function:

```
Function CountVisibleRows(rg As Range)
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    ' Count visible cells in the first column, minus one to account for the header
    NumRows = rg.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
    CountVisibleRows = NumRows
End Function
```

I then tested this on the range before copying and determined the number of rows that would be copied (because the Copy() method copies only visible rows by default).